# Javascript Array Showing Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap, associative-array

I am confused regarding javascript arrays and how the indices work in these arrays. The length of the array is always 0 no matter how many key value elements are there in the array. Also we can see that the array has only two elements provided that the key is string. Lets consider scenario 1, i have following code.

```js
arr = [];
arr['home'] = 1234;
arr['cat'] = 12345;
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr);
```

Now consider second scenario, i have an empty array and i assign some number to the 20th index of the array. Then when i output the array, the length shows 21 with all the other locations being 'undefined'.

```js
arr = [];
arr[20] = 20;
console.log(arr.length); // Length shows 20 Size of array increased to 21
```

Now in the third scenario i will assign both numbered indices and string indices and it shows another strange behavior. The length of the array doesn't count the value with string based index. Even though i have 4 number indices and one string based index. So the length should be 6 but the length shows 5.

```js
arr = [];
arr[4] = 4;
arr['home'] = 'home';
console.log(arr);
```

Now i have two questions.Firstly, Why is the length function not considering string indexed item? Secondly, Why in the case of numbered indices, does the array size is increased to atleast that number?

Comment: arrays can only have numeric keys

Comment: Did you even try to run the code. This is javascript i have asked question about - @RolandStarke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand that JavaScript arrays are objects, with some additional behavior. Just like objects, you can assign properties to them.

If the property's name is a numeric string and there is no higher numeric key, the `length` property is updated. Non-numeric keys don't affect the `length` property.

The methods in `Array.prototype` (`filter`, `slice`, ...) only work with the numeric keys of the array.

Comment: Not just any numeric property. Only "integer" properties between 0 and 2^32-1.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript doesn't have associative arrays like you see in PHP.  It has arrays, which have a numerical index associated with the value, and then it has objects which are mapped key => value.

[Javascript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Javascript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(arr.length); // outputs 7

const obj = {}

console.log(obj.length); // undefined

// set the key => value for obj from arr

arr.forEach(a => obj[a] = a);

console.log(obj[0]); // undefined
console.log(obj[1]); // 1

console.log(arr[0]); // 1
console.log(arr[1]); // 2
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/qiposop/edit?js,console)

In the example above, you can see that arr is an array and its values are mapped index => value, while obj is an object and its values are mapped key => value.  Objects can function as hash maps/associative arrays, but arrays cannot.

If you were to want to get the number of values in an object/hash map, you can always do...

Object.keys(obj).length

This is because `Object.keys(...)` returns the keys of an object as an array.

For an accurate answer, I should clarify that arrays are objects, however, they function differently than an object inherently does.  Per the docs, arrays are "high-level, list-like objects"

Comment: I agree it doesn't have associative arrays. But how come the same array i declared has numeric as well as string indexed items? @kyle

Comment: @BILALAHMAD: did you read the other answer? Arrays are objects. Objects can have arbitrary properties.